# Get a set of closest numbers from array?

Tags: calculus

I'm not very good at math but I need to know how to get a set of numbers that are closest to each other.

It means that if I have 5 numbers `[-1, 2, 7, 11, 3222]`. Now it is obvious (to me) without any rules to see that correct numbers would be `-1, 2, 7, 11` or even `-1, 2, 7`. However I have no idea how to implement some kind of rule that will allow programatically filter a set of numbers and get *viable* ones.

You can clearly see that simple solutions like calculating median from all numbers and then getting closest numbers to it would be wrong.

Maybe if I would take median of all numbers except `3222`, calculate median, get all numbers from set that are +10/-10 it would work well, however, how do I make computer know that `3222` does not belong here...

So basically I'm pretty stuck here. As I said I'm not very good with math so don't judge me by asking this *silly* question.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "closest" here? I do not really see a pattern in your example, except "the differences are small"...

Comment: I would recommend posting to the statistics website to ask "how do I recognize the outliers in a given data set?"

Comment: What sequences are you looking at ... what are - in your model of "closeness" - the closest numbers in $[1,2,3, 1000, 1001, 1002]$, the median ansatz doesn't fit well here.

Comment: @JohannesKloos Well I would say that closest ones are the ones who are in rage of +50 and -50. Like in example that I wrote - if I take away `3222`, calculate average of the ones who are left and than take everything from set that is +50 and -50 I would have a viable array.

Comment: @martini yes, I didn't see that. Too bad, however in my data sets there is only 1-3 numbers that are so big compared to others. So if I ignore this problem is it still possible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for advice, will do.

Comment: Would something like [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) help here? Perhaps not directly. But might give some useful ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You might one to sort your data in an increasing (or decreasing, I have no problem with that) order and compute a coarse discrete derivative. Then you can split your data in a certain number of groups (let's call them clusters) which are "dense".

For instance, if you have a serie as follows: $[1, 2, 9, 7, 260, 6, 5, -8, 255, -300, -2, 0, 15, -302]$ you can sort them using a [quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (you can find some fast implementation) and you get: $[-302, -300, -8, -2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15, 255, 260]$ (hope I didn't forget any) and apply a simple finite difference filter $[-1, 1]$ on you vector which gives you $[2, 242, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 6, 240, 5]$. Having a look at this serie clearly tells you that you have three groups of number and the high peaks in the derivative tells you how to split your numbers.

This is a really naive approach. If you have really large, evolving data, you might want to have a look at (online) clustering algorithm.

Hope it helped